# The use of words 'right' and 'rightful'

Tags: phrase-request

If I am supposed to do something for someone as it is their right that I do this for them. I have to do four things, for example for that person. I say:

> 1. **It is your right upon me that I do four things for you.**

Is this sensible enough? Or should we not say this thing in this way? If not, can we say:

> 2. You're rightful that I do four things for you.
> 3. There are four rights of yours upon me.
> 4. There are four things as your right upon me.

Comment: Look up "rightful" in a dictionary. I don't believe it is ever used of a person, but of actions or situations.

Answer (score 1):

I think about 2 ways to better say that:

> You are entitled to get four things done by me.

or:

> I owe you four things, it is in your right to take benefit of it.

---

As implied by @NathanTuggy's answer, **favors** is a better suited than **things** in the context.

---

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entitle):

> **(to) entitle** (vb.) (ALLOW) = to give someone the right to do or have something:
>
> - Being unemployed entitles you to free medical treatment.
> - The employer is entitled to ask for references.

Answer (score 1):

#1 sounds archaic and confusing. (It is not, as far as I know, an actual English usage, past or present.) #2-4 are almost impossible to understand, and #4 sounds, again, like a botched (non-existent) archaism.

The simplest way to say this is probably:

> I owe you four favors.

This means that, on four occasions, the other person can ask for something and have you give it to them, do it, etc. Maybe they picked up the tab for you four times and now you have to pay them back. (Or maybe they saved your life four times.)

Alternatively, if you have a *continuing* duty for four *kinds* of things, you would need to say something closer to

> I owe you **these** four duties: [description of first], [second], [third], and [fourth].

This sounds more archaic, mostly because modern English culture doesn't usually enumerate duties this way. But in this case you have to specify that it's not just four, but a *particular* set of four (using "these") and then probably list them (since it otherwise would not be clear which ones you were talking about).